# Permanently change keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dpkg, reboot, gnome-settings-daemon

I am using Xmonad and LXDE, so I don't want to use gnome-settings-daemon. But there is a problem - without it I cannot switch into or type in Cyrillics. I found some temporary solution - when I enter `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and click through config menu, I end with right layout. But after I reboot system it disappears and I am forced to reconfigure it again. Is there a way to make this changes permanent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes edit /etc/default/keyboard to set the global settings or ~/.dmrc for per-user settings.

Example /etc/default/keyboard:

```
 XKBMODEL="pc105"
 XKBLAYOUT="fr,us"
 XKBVARIANT="oss"
 XKBOPTIONS="compose:ralt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

Example ~/.dmrc:

```
 [Desktop]
 Language=de_DE.UTF-8   # change to your default lang
 Layout=de   nodeadkeys # change to your keyboard layout
```

In either case, will need to also run:

```
 sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

Comment: Can you explain what the last step does in detail and why one needs it?

Comment: udev is the service that manages your devices.  The command signals to this service that there's been a change to your input subsystem and that it should re-detect things and reconfigure.  Rebooting your system should have the same effect.