# How to keep keyboard settings using setxkbmap across reboot?

Tags: lubuntu, language-support, input-language, hebrew

Searching the forum, I found the following to add Hebrew support for Lubuntu (Typing in Hebrew):
`setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il`

The problem is that after I reboot my computer, it doesn't work anymore and I have to type it again.

Suggestions?

Comment: as seen in http://askubuntu.com/questions/121474/permanently-change-keyboard-layout , you can edit /etc/default/keyboard. XKBLAYOUT would be "us,il" and the rest under XKBOPTIONS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!