# Can't type apostrophe, deadkeys do not work (bionic)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I use Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, and I use **us(alt-intl)** as a keyboard layout for Latin script, because sometimes I need type multilingual texts. Today I got very strange bug: now I cannot use the sign ' (apostrophe). When I press the key `<AC11>` assigned to apostrophe, I get nothing. When I press space key after that, I get space. When I press <`AC11>` + e.g. "a", I get "a", not "á". When I press SHIFT + `<AC11>`, I also get nothing. So, I can't type " (quotation mark) too.

The website [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/) tells (pressing `<AC11>`): *222, event.key Dead, event.location 0 (General keys), event.which(deprecated) 222, event.code Quote*

My /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose has such a rows (nothing abnormal):

```
# Spacing versions of dead accents
<dead_acute> <space>                    : "'"   apostrophe # APOSTROPHE
<dead_acute> <dead_acute>               : "´"   acute # ACUTE ACCENT
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <apostrophe>   : "´"   acute # ACUTE ACCENT
```

In addition, when I use AltGr typing with **us(alt-intl),** it also doesn't work, but when I type Cyrillic texts with **ru(udm),** AltGr works normally.

Any advices, please.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd><AC11></kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> results in á for me with that layout.

[Bug #1573755](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755) comes to mind. For test purposes I suggest that you create an additional user, log in as that user, and find out if the issue is still present.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, the link you provided was very useful. I have solved my problem using  'ibus-setup' and 'im-config'. I don't fully understand what I did, but now all works. I suspect that the problem was concerned with concurrence between input methods.

Comment: @udmnews: Ah, good. Possibly you had XIM enabled and switched to IBus. Doing so proved to solve the problem for some users who have commented on that bug report.

Comment: Thanks again. I've browsed a few old related topics here, e.g. this one [https://askubuntu.com/questions/88877/how-can-i-fix-my-keyboard-layout?rq=1]. Traces of iBus are evident :-)

Comment: @udmnews: Nah, that question is about something else I think. But if you open the _Language Support_ tool, you can easily see which "Keyboard input method system" you have selected.

Comment: Yes, of course. But there was no need to check that parameter for many years :)

Comment: @udmnews: Right, and that's what makes this bug so subtle. Suddenly some cache gets too large or gets corrupted somehow and stops dead keys from working.